# Variable action name zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to make a password reset link and I want to know if I can make an action with the name of the token. So I will access the link like this site.com/auth/resetpassword/token.

I can't find anything documented on the internet.

I'm generating my token like this:

```
$lengthSalt = 24;
$token = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, $lengthSalt);
```

Comment: Why would you want a variable action name? Your token is a parameter, not an action.

Comment: I'm guessing it was mistake. From URL i guess "resetpassword" is an action name.

Comment: @MaciejJaśniaczyk resetpassword is an action name, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define proper route

Example for Zend 1.10: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.controller.router.html

```
$router = $ctrl->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default
$router->addRoute(
    'resetpass',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('auth/resetpassword/:token',
                                     array('controller' => 'auth',
                                           'action' => 'resetpassword'))
);
```

This depends on the way you define your routes, there are more than one way to do it.

EDIT: If you want to work with default routes, you'll need to use this pattern: www.yoursite.com/controller/action/var1/value1/var2/value2.

So for you, it would be site.com/auth/resetpassword/token/[token], where in place of [token] you put your token value.

Then, you can acces your variable in controller:

```
$token = $this->getRequest()->getParam('token');
```

Comment: This is how I did it and it's not working:

$password = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/auth/resetpassword/reset/:token',
            array('controller' => 'Forgotpassword', 'action' => 'reset'));

accesing auth/forgotpassword/reset/token/asdadadasada will not display anything (I've put a var_dump on token).
"auth" is the module, not the controller.

Comment: Well, could you explain what exactly isn't working? What url are you testing this on (including params)? Is action firing properly?

Comment: site/auth/forgotpassword/reset/ it's working. 
site/auth/forgotpassword/reset/token/[token] it's not working. 
so yes, the action is firing properly.

Comment: So what isn't working? Are you using standard routes? In that case auth is your controller, forgotpassword is action, what's reset?

Comment: Someone who worked on the project before me, made the routes like this: 
$all = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/auth/:controller/:action',
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));

after this one, I added the route like above.

Comment: Ok, so you don't use standard routes. The route you pasted doesn't accept any additional params. Change it to Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/auth/:controller/:action/*' [...]. With route i posted as example, your url should look like site/auth/forgotpassword/token/[token] (without reset)